# How to shift and cycle characters in python

Tags: python, string, modulo

I want to increase each character's ASCII value, and cycle (wraparound) if value > `z`.

```
#small chars:
for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print factName + '(' + char + ', ' + chr(((ord(char)+key) % ord('z'))) + ').'
```

if `key = 3` >> `a` became `d` but `w`, `x`, and `y` are not correct!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you reduced everything mod ord('z'), as if the alphabet's internal values were zero-based.  As you've discovered, this is *not* the case.  Instead, you need to make that overflow check, and then subtract the width of your data set.  The basic logic is

```
if ord(chr) + key > ord('z'):
    result = ord(chr) + key - 26
```

Is that enough to get you moving?

You can also do this with a simple translation table, building a new alphabet from the old: cut the first 3 characters and append them to the back of your translation string:

```
blank_code = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
new_code = blank_code[-n:] + blank_code[:n]
```

This gives you a corresponding "alphabet" to use.  Also see the `translate` method for a quick way to use these.